# Sonarqube and SAML 2.0

Tags: sonarqube, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, cas

So I am running Sonarqube and I have LDAP integration to my system.

Now we would like to add SAML to all our systems. We have already successfully done it in artifactory, jira, confluence, etc. My problem is that Sonarqubes CAS plugin went old in 3.3 and I am running 5.3 ->

So first how do I open a ticket about this to Sonarqube?

What has changed in CAS and could I use it as a bottom to create SAML 2.0 plugin for Sonarqube?

Is there any other way of doing this?

Any idea how much has changed in this? Should I just start from empty table writing this?

If you can answer any of these I would be grateful.